# Python - Numpy search across multiple columns in a CSV

Tags: python, search, numpy, multiple-columns

I have a `CSV` with 7 columns:

```
low low 5more   more    big high    vgood
vhigh   vhigh   2   2   small   low unacc
vhigh   vhigh   2   2   small   med unacc
vhigh   vhigh   2   2   small   high    unacc
vhigh   vhigh   2   2   med low unacc
vhigh   vhigh   2   2   med med unacc
vhigh   vhigh   2   2   med high    unacc
```

I need to search for values `high` or `vhigh` in columns `0`, `1`, and `5`. I am not sure how `NumPy`'s various search functions can accomplish this (I need to use `NumPy` for this search).

Can someone help? Much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]!  What your asking isn't too difficult, but nobody has answered probably because you're not being very specific with what you want, nor shown how you've tried to do it.  Do you want to know _which_ rows have those values, or do you want to get the rows themselves?  What format is your 'csv' in?  Is that the file, or were you able to load it into a numpy array?

Answer (score 2):

If what you've shown is a file, you can load it with

```
In [259]: arr = np.genfromtxt('tmp.csv', names=True, dtype=None)

In [260]: arr
Out[260]: 
array([('vhigh', 'vhigh', 2, 2, 'small',  'low', 'unacc'),
       ('vhigh', 'vhigh', 2, 2, 'small',  'med', 'unacc'),
       ('vhigh', 'vhigh', 2, 2, 'small', 'high', 'unacc'),
       ('vhigh', 'vhigh', 2, 2,   'med',  'low', 'unacc'),
       ('vhigh', 'vhigh', 2, 2,   'med',  'med', 'unacc'),
       ('vhigh', 'vhigh', 2, 2,   'med', 'high', 'unacc')], 
      dtype=[('low', 'S5'), ('low_1', 'S5'), ('5more', '<i8'), ('more', '<i8'), ('big', 'S5'), ('high', 'S4'), ('vgood', 'S5')])
```

To "search", there are a few interpretations.  For all of them, we'll want to look at one column at a time.  Let's look at column `5` (sixth from left, labeled `high` in the top row which I've assumed is the header of the column). It looks like this:

```
In [268]: arr['high']
Out[268]: 
array(['low', 'med', 'high', 'low', 'med', 'high'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

You can see which rows the `'high'` column has `'high'` as its value with direct comparison:

```
In [269]: arr['high'] == 'high'
Out[269]: array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

You can see the indices for this with `where`:

```
In [270]: np.where(arr['high'] == 'high')
Out[270]: (array([2, 5]),)
```

Or you can just get the rows where the `'high'` row has `'high'` in it:

```
In [271]: arr[arr['high'] == 'high']
Out[271]: 
array([('vhigh', 'vhigh', 2, 2, 'small', 'high', 'unacc'),
       ('vhigh', 'vhigh', 2, 2, 'med', 'high', 'unacc')], 
      dtype=[('low', 'S5'), ('low_1', 'S5'), ('5more', '<i8'), ('more', '<i8'), ('big', 'S5'), ('high', 'S4'), ('vgood', 'S5')])
```

If you want to search for both `'vhigh'` and `'high'` at once, you can use `np.char.endswith` (or `np.char.count` if it's not necessarily an ending), which will get either:

```
In [272]: np.char.endswith(arr['low'], 'high')
Out[272]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [273]: np.char.endswith(arr['high'], 'high')
Out[273]: array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

To put it all together, you can check which rows have all three with:

```
In [290]: np.all([arr['low'] == 'vhigh', arr['low_1'] == 'vhigh', arr['high'] == 'high'], 0)
Out[290]: array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

---

Since you no longer have the integer columns `5more` and `more`, you could just make an ordinary string array:

```
In [293]: b = np.column_stack([arr['low'], arr['low_1'], arr['high']])

In [294]: b
Out[294]: 
array([['vhigh', 'vhigh', 'low'],
       ['vhigh', 'vhigh', 'med'],
       ['vhigh', 'vhigh', 'high'],
       ['vhigh', 'vhigh', 'low'],
       ['vhigh', 'vhigh', 'med'],
       ['vhigh', 'vhigh', 'high']], 
      dtype='|S5')

In [295]: np.char.endswith(b, 'high')
Out[295]: 
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [297]: np.all(np.char.endswith(b, 'high'), 1)
Out[297]: array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```